# Access lists via REST within a SharePoint hosted add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to access lists within SP hosted add in from outside its context.

Using the Content Editor WebPart I have placed some javascript (to make the request) on a sub site of my site collection e.g.https://work.sharepoint.com/teams/d/sandbox/

My SP app addin is hosted in the same site collection e.g.
https://work-9850ba148f9a52.sharepoint.com/teams/d/MyApp/

I am using the following code to try and get the lists data from the add in but it gives me a 403 error.

Maybe I have mixed up the hostweburl and the appweburl?

Advice appreciated!

```
function GetLists() {

var executor;
var hostweburl= "https://work-9850ba148f9a52.sharepoint.com/teams/d/MyApp/"
var appweburl = "https://work.sharepoint.com/teams/d/sandbox/"

executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(hostweburl);
executor.executeAsync(
{url: appweburl + "_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {

            console.log(data);

        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Refer this MSDN code -- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/access-sharepoint-data-from-add-ins-using-the-cross-domain-library

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your executor:

```
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
```

It should be appweburl instead of hostweburl.

Comment: I have updated the executor to appweburl but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have give adequate permissions in the Appmanifest.xml file.

It should be site collection read atleast to get data from the site collection.

SP-hosted app works on user+app permission. So, ensure that the user has adequate permission to read data from the list.

[image]

If its not give, please provide permission and then upload the app again.

Comment: The SiteCollection permission is set to FullControl in the Appmanifest.xml. Any ideas?

Comment: how about changing values of host web and app web to `var hostweburl = "https://work.sharepoint.com/teams/d/sandbox/"
var appweburl= "https://work-9850ba148f9a52.sharepoint.com/teams/d/MyApp/" `  ?

Answer (score 0):

Please access appweb and hostweb url like below instead of hard code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Set the style of the client web part page to be consistent with the host web.
        (function () {
            'use strict';
            var hostUrl = '';
            if (document.URL.indexOf('?') != -1) {
                var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var p = decodeURIComponent(params[i]);
                    if (/^SPHostUrl=/i.test(p)) {
                        hostUrl = p.split('=')[1];
                        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + hostUrl + '/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx" />');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hostUrl == '') {
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/themable/corev15.css" />');
            }
        })();
    </script>

    <%-- Internal blog --%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var hostweburl;
        var appweburl;
        // Load the required SharePoint libraries
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Get the URI decoded URLs.
            hostweburl =
                decodeURIComponent(
                    getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
            );
            appweburl =
                decodeURIComponent(
                    getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
            );
            // resources are in URLs in the form:
            // web_url/_layouts/15/resource
            var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
            // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
        });
        // Function to prepare and issue the request to get
        //  SharePoint data
        function execCrossDomainRequest() {
            // executor: The RequestExecutor object
            // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
            var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
            // Issue the call against the app web.
            // To get the title using REST we can hit the endpoint:
            //      appweburl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
            // The response formats the data in the JSON format.
            // The functions successHandler and errorHandler attend the
            //      sucess and error events respectively.
            executor.executeAsync(
                {
                    url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items?@target='" + hostweburl + "/blog'&$top=1",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                    success: successHandler,
                    error: errorHandler
                }
            );
        }
        // Function to handle the success event.
        // Prints the data to the page.
        function successHandler(data) {
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
            var blogsHTML = "";
            var results = jsonObject.d.results;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                blogsHTML = blogsHTML + "<div><a href=\"" + hostweburl + "/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=" + results[i].ID + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + results[i].Title + "</a></div><br>";
            }
            $('#internal').append(blogsHTML);
        }
        // Function to handle the error event.
        // Prints the error message to the page.
        function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
            document.getElementById("internal").innerText =
                "Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorMessage;
        }
        // Function to retrieve a query string value.
        // For production purposes you may want to use
        //  a library to handle the query string.
        function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
            var params =
                document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
            var strParams = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
                var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
                if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                    return singleParam[1];
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And here is the complete demo about accessing host web list in SharePoint add-in:

[Build a SharePoint Hosted App to access list data in your Host Web using the REST API in 10 Easy Steps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickpinheiro/2015/01/30/build-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-to-access-list-data-in-your-host-web-using-the-rest-api-in-10-easy-steps/)